# So I designed a logo in Illustrator using just text which I'm looking to have it printed, can it still be used as a vector

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, print-design, logo, resolution

Basically, what the title says, I designed a logo in Illustrator which I'm planning to print as stickers using just text/fonts.

Will I be able to export/save it as a vector and have it printed? My aim is a 9x9cm circular sticker.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this very elementary question is answered fully in the application Help Files. While this question may inquire about commonly used graphic design tools, this has little to do with actual graphic design.

Comment: Basically if it is in ilustrator is vector. I really do not see the point of your question either.

Comment: Aditionally you are making comments on the comments and asking aditional guidence, which renders the original answers... usless.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Just make sure you outline your type first.

Right-click, Create outlines

[image]

To add to Vicki's comment, I usually save my "working" documents (with editable text) as .ai files.  I then save my outlined, print-ready designs as .eps or .pdf files, depending on which the printer asks for.  That way, you can always go back and change something if need be, as she stated.

Comment: I'll add that before converting your text to outlines, you might want to make a copy of your editable text and save it either in another document, or on a hidden layer, just in case you need to make edits later.

Comment: I work with my editable text in .ai files and will save my outlined, print-ready designs as an .eps or .pdf

Comment: That works too! :)

Comment: Thanks. So I create outlines and just save it as it is? Or do I delete the fillings after creating outlines?

Comment: @DimitriK if you send your printer empty paths, how will they know what color(s) you want to use in your logo?  Just outline them and leave them filled.

Comment: Will do thanks. Do I select high quality print for the PDF preset?

Comment: @DimitriK Since you have only paths, yeah that should work fine.  If you had images, you would probably want to edit the compression settings for those, but that's getting outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
The text typed in Illustrator is vector-based.

Just save your file as PDF, and make sure the font is included in the "Save Adobe PDF"-dialog when you save the file.

[image: Adobe Illustrator - Save Adobe PDF]

There should be no need to outline the text as long as the font is allowed to be included in the PDF file. If you for some reason *must* make an EPS-file, you should outline the text.

To verify that all is OK in the PDF, you can check the file properties in Acrobat.

This screenshot from a random downloaded PDF the "Document properties" (Norwegian language) shows that fonts are embeded. ("innebygd delsett" = "embeded subset")

[image: Acrobat - Document Prpoerties]

If this is a logo that you are delivering to a customer, outlining it might be best practice, as this will stop them from ruining it if they are to make changes and don't have the font you have used. But you should not *need* to outline it before sending it to print.

Comment: thanks for that. It's not a logo I'm delivering to a customer, just one that I'll have printed for my personal use. :) It'll mainly be printed on a 9x9cm rounded sticker, will PDF still be fine seeing as I guess it has to be on a transparent background? Does Illustrator do that?

Comment: PDF should be fine for that purpose as well, yes. There is no background in Illustrator-documents unless you manually add one :)

Comment: thanks again, you've been very helpful. I don't normally use Illustrator, it's always been Photoshop for me but I knew for a fact that Illustrator would be better for prints and such so that's why I'm giving it a go.

One last question, does my document have to be in the same exact size I want the actual print to be?

Comment: As a best practice you should. But it does not *need* to be, as vector graphics are scalable. The one printing the stickers for you should be able to scale it to the size you have specified. To avoid mistakes though, I would have given it the correct dimensions as long as that is possible.